# jQuery filter function is not showing exact match :(

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is something like this,
I am using filter function to show the matched elements(LI)in tree,its working fine but its showing all li elements which starts from passed string,for example
if i passed "Application" to filter function,then it's showing me all li, which text start from "Application"

```
function callme(filterData){
$("ul.treeview").find("li").hide();
if(filterData.indexOf("|")!=-1){
    var filterData = filterData.split("|");

    for(i=0;i<filterData.length;i++){

        jQuery("ul.treeview").find("li").filter(function(index) {
            return jQuery.trim($(this).text()) == filterData.trim();
        }).show();
    }

}else{
    jQuery("ul.treeview").find("li").filter(function(index) {
        return jQuery.trim($(this).text()) == filterData.trim();
    }).show();

}
}
```

here is my html...

`<ul id="leftNavigation" class="treeview">  
   <li>
        <ul>
      <li >
        <a href="#">Application</a><font   class="leftNavHitsFont"> - (3)</font>
      </li>
       </ul>
       <ul>
    <li >
    <a href="#">Application Notes</a><font class="leftNavHitsFont"> - (1)</font>
   </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>`

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example of this failing?  If not could work up a quick mockup so I can see the html you are working off of?

Comment: @antonlavey  i have updated my scenario with html also

Comment: @Jacob Relkin yes i am trying,i will let you know within few minutes if it works

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: @Nick Craver i am trying this in mozila and ie8

Comment: @Vivek - `.trim();` isn't a function in IE8, you should be seeing an error there.

Comment: @Nick Craver No, i am not getting any error in ie8,but for time being, if i removed .trim(),then also result is same.

Comment: Actually this code is working fine if i have only li tags within ul,but if we have some thing like ul then li,again ul inside li,then li inside ul and so on(As i have written in my question)...then this approch is not working fine

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that is the definition of something *containing* something else.

Maybe you meant to get an exact match?

```
jQuery("ul.treeview").find("li").filter(function(index) {
    return jQuery.trim($(this).text()) == jQuery.trim(filterData);
}).show();
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gAnyM/)

Comment: what i am doing in my code is, first hiding all li,then trying to show only those li which matches to passed string in filter()

Comment: i have updated my question with my function,which i am calling on button click

Comment: yes i saw that on jsFiddle,but i am not getting why it's not working in my code?

Comment: i tried on jsFiddle with my html as i written in my question, there, its also not working.